# How to calculate the magnetic field with a square Amperian loop?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

So I am kind of confused with Ampère's theorem, specifically when you have to use a square loop. Let's say I have a cylinder centered on the $z$ axis and there is a uniform surface current in the $\hat{\phi}$ direction. I want to find the magnetic field inside the cylinder.

What I would do is use a square amperian loop of dimension $L$ going through the cylinder with one half inside and the other half outside of it. I would then calculate the line integral of the loop by adding the contribution of each sides (it would be zero for sides parallel to $\hat{r}$) which would mean I get $2BL$. However, apparently the result of that integral is $BL$. Why is that? Am I supposed to only calculate one side? Do I only calculate it for the side that is actually inside the cylinder? It kind of confuses me because why would we make a loop if we are not going to integrate over the whole thing?

Comment: What is the magnetic field outside the cylinder? Does it differ from the field inside? What is its contribution to the integral along the Amperian loop?

Comment: @Puk Oh right I understand now. The magnetic field is zero outside so that side just amounts to zero. Thank you. I don't know how I missed that.